# python interpolation showing both result at once

Tags: python-3.x

i am having problem while writing a general interpolation code.Actually it was suppose to give me corresponding value y for each input (x), and was suppose to print `out of range` when the value of x is less than or greater than the value of x from list. But it is showing both result and the Out of range print at the same time for any value of x.

```
a=float(input("Enter the value of X:"))
x=[1.0,2.1,5.0]
y=[8.0,20.6,13.7]
i=0
lenx=len(x)
for i in range (2):
    if a <= x[i]:
        y=float(y[i-1]+((y[i]-y[i-1])/(x[i]-x[i-1]))*(a-x[i-1]))
        print(y)
    else:
        print("The value is out of range")
```

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense. What is the code supposed to output? Why do you replace the list `y` with a single value? Is the `else` supposed to be for the `if` (as it's indented) or the `for` (which I think would make more sense, but then as the `if` never includes a `break` it would never be invoked)?

Comment: Sorry but what i was trying to do was in the range of the `2` because my list contains only 3 point . If the value is less than anyone of them then the formula would apply accordingly depending on `i` and if the value is not less than any of the above list then it will give a output the the value is out of range but i guess i did it in he wrong way.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mcve] showing example inputs with expected and actual output.